# Not able to execute binary and set env in node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

Is this correct syntax for executing binary by passing path?. This is the code

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var binaryFile = '/path/project/bin/file';
var result = spawn(binaryFile + ' ' + arg, [process.env.HOME]);
        result.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: I can execute binaryFile arg on command line tool. Here arg is username which binary takes and generate hash.

Comment: binaryFile is a executable which takes a user name as param.  There are other binary file I am able to execute but only issue here is I need to set home directory.  For example I can run execute GenLib binary successfully exec(GenLib + ' ' + email)

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated.